# Check if user exists and belong to group

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I want to check three conditions before I run the command: If string (username) match to regexp, if user exists and if user belongs to certain group:

```
PASSWORD=`/usr/bin/pwgen -sync -1 15`
CHPASSWD=/usr/sbin/chpasswd
FILE=/tmp/password
USER_GROUP=somegroup

while true
  do
    echo -ne "username: "; read USER_NAME
      if [[ "$USER_NAME" =~ ^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*[$]?$ ]] &&
         [[ `getent group $USER_GROUP | grep -o $USER_NAME` -eq 0 ]] &&
         [[ `getent passwd $USER_NAME | cut -d ':' -f -1` -eq 0 ]]
      then
        break
      else
        echo "error"
      fi
  done

echo $USER_NAME:$PASSWORD > $FILE
sudo $CHPASSWD < $FILE
rm -f $FILE
```

The above code works partially only. It checks for regexp and group but it is trying to change password for even if user doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself. Your own variables should choose names with at least one lower-case character to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Beyond that -- I'd consider `while read -p "username: " username; do` so your loop exits as soon as the `read` fails. And you have lots of missing quotes -- run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...beyond that, I'd suggest identifying the specific test that fails, and building a [mre] that reflects it. Using `set -x` to run your code with trace-level logging will do a lot of good to let you know exactly which line, and which condition, is the piece that first behaves contrary to expectations, to allow a more narrowly focused question.

Comment: (Also, it doesn't look to me like all your pipelines emit numeric outputs, even though you're comparing their stdout _to numbers_, via `-eq` -- a strictly numeric-comparison operator).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I change `if` statement to: ```if [[ "$USER_NAME" =~ ^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*[$]?$ ]] && [[ `getent group $USER_GROUP | grep -o $USER_NAME` == $USER_NAME ]]``` and enter `john` as input then it is trying to change password despite there is only `johnwayne` user. So clearly I need better validation.

Comment: So, what does the `set -x` log say those `[[ ]]`s are actually using as active values?

Comment: (and yes, `echo johnwayne | grep john` finds a match, since it's just checking substrings, not individual words).

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is:

```
while true
do
  echo -ne "username: "; read USER_NAME
    if [[ "$USER_NAME" =~ ^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*[$]?$ ]]
      then
        if [[ `getent group $USER_GROUP | grep -w -c "$USER_NAME"` -eq 1 ]]
          then
            break
          else
            echo "User not in the right group"
          fi
        else
          echo "Invalid characters"
      fi
done
```